# What can I use to show/hide a clickable button?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to use a "hidden" div that will contain a click-able image link based on a PHP return value.

Can someone please point me to an example? I know there is a name for this but I don't know what it's called.

Comment: I'm totally not sure what you mean by this. Should the div and it's clickable content be hidden? Please be more specific.

Comment: Litso, I thought I was specific. Yes, the div as well as the linked button should be hidden until it gets a response back from PHP

Comment: In some of your comments you suggest scrapping using jquery and solving the problem with PHP.  jquery is a client-side script and the hiding/showing will take place on the client system.  PHP is a server-side script and will require a trip back to the server to hide/show your button(s).  The trip back to the server may be OK in this case because hide/show is to be the result of a PHP call.  You'll need to decide where you want the decision to hide/show something to be made.

Answer (score 1):

Show: ([api url](http://api.jquery.com/show/))

```
$("#mybuttondivID").show();
```

Hide: ([api url](http://api.jquery.com/hide/))

```
$("#mybuttondivID").hide();
```

An example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Show/Hide example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mybuttondiv">
        <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://www.google.be/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="Google" /></a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // hide the buttondiv before we do the ajax call
            $("#mybuttondiv").hide();

            //do an ajax request to a php page
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "fetch_data.php",
                success: function (html) {
                    //do something when the response returns
                    // in this case, we make the button visible again
                    $("#mybuttondiv").show();
                },
                error: function (request) {
                    //ajax failed, display button again
                    $("#mybuttondiv").show();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a link to the jquery `$.Ajax` help page:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the answer. I am totally jquery illiterate so is there an example that you can point me to so I can see the code?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example for what "I think" you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for a combination of [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and/or [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)?

**EDIT:** Based on your comment above, maybe this is what you're after:

```
var hidden = $('#someDiv, #someLink').hide();
$.get('someScript.php', function() {
    hidden.show();
});
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for the answer. I really have no idea what I need. What you posted may be the ticket but I am really jquery illiterate. I'm about ready to just scrap the entire jquery library and do this in straight php.

Comment: It was a bit unclear exactly what outcome you're after. If this is something that PHP can handle simply, I would definitely recommend it instead of loading the entire jQuery library.

Comment: Thanks again Kevin. Isn't there supposed to be a success in there somewhere? If there is a success back from the server, I'd like to show the clickable image link.